# SDL - The object Oriented Way

Tags: c++, error-handling, sdl, render

Apologize if this is too long of a post. I'm merely trying to get SDL to work in an object oriented fashion - there's no point in me moving on until I get past this point. Been spending a fair amount of time compiling this and getting errors. I'll post my header files and sources, along with my makefile and an output to see what's going on.

Here's **render.h**:

```
#ifndef RENDER_H
#define RENDER_H

#include <string>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

using std::string;

class Render
{
public:
        Render(string filename, int x, int y, SDL_Surface * destination);
    ~Render();
private:
    SDL_Surface * m_optimizedImage;

    void load_image(string filename);
    void apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface * source, SDL_Surface * destination);
};

#endif
```

...and **render.cpp**:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <string>
#include "render.h"

using std::string;

Render::Render(string filename, int x, int y, SDL_Surface * destination)
{
    this->m_optimizedImage = NULL;
    load_image(filename);
    apply_surface(x, y, m_optimizedImage, destination);

}

Render::~Render()
{
    delete m_optimizedImage;
}

void Render::load_image(string filename)
{
    SDL_Surface * loadedImage = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());

    if (loadedImage != NULL)
    {
        m_optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(loadedImage);

        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    }
}

void Render::apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface * source, SDL_Surface * destination)
{
    SDL_Rect offset;

    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    SDL_BlitSurface(source, NULL, destination, &offset);

}
```

...and **screenwriter.h**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>



#ifndef SCREENWRITER_H
#define SCREENWRITER_H

class ScreenWriter
{
public:

    ~ScreenWriter();

    bool flip_screen();
    void delay_screen(int milliseconds);

    bool get_screen_state() const;
    static ScreenWriter& get_instance();

    SDL_Surface * get_screen() const;
private:
    ScreenWriter();

    void initialize();
    bool m_screenFailure;

    SDL_Surface * m_screen;

};

#endif
```

...and **screenwriter.cpp**:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include "screenwriter.h"

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480
#define SCREEN_BPP 32

ScreenWriter::ScreenWriter()
{
    this->m_screenFailure = false;
    initialize();
}

ScreenWriter::~ScreenWriter()
{

    SDL_Quit();
}

ScreenWriter& ScreenWriter::get_instance() 
{
    static ScreenWriter instance;

    return instance;
}

SDL_Surface * ScreenWriter::get_screen() const
{
    return m_screen;
}

bool ScreenWriter::get_screen_state() const
{
    return this->m_screenFailure;
}

void ScreenWriter::delay_screen(int milliseconds)
{
    SDL_Delay(milliseconds);
}

int ScreenWriter::flip_screen()
{

    if (SDL_Flip(m_screen) == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        SDL_Flip(m_screen);
        return 0;
    }

}

void ScreenWriter::initialize()
{
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING == -1))
        {
                std::cout << "SDL_Init has failed";
        }
        else
        {

                SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
                //initialize screen
                this->m_screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH,
                                                  SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                                                  SCREEN_BPP,
                                                  SDL_SWSURFACE);

                if (m_screen == NULL)
                {
                        this->m_screenFailure = true;
                }
                else
                {
                        this->m_screenFailure = false;
                }

                //set caption header
                SDL_WM_SetCaption("Hello WOrld", NULL);
        }

}
```

...and of course **main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include "screenwriter.h"
#include "render.h"

int main(int argc, char * args[])
{
    std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;

    ScreenWriter * instance = ScreenWriter::get_instance();

    instance->flip_screen();

    Render render = new Render("look.png", 0, 0, instance->get_screen());

    delete instance();

    return 0;
}
```

...my **output**:

```
g++ -c main.cpp render.h screenwriter.h -lSDL -lSDL_image
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:10:55: error: cannot convert ‘ScreenWriter’ to ‘ScreenWriter*’ in initialization
main.cpp:12:69: error: conversion from ‘Render*’ to non-scalar type ‘Render’ requested
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

...my **makefile**

```
program : main.o render.o screenwriter.o
    g++ -o program main.o render.o screenwriter.o -lSDL -lSDL_image

main.o : main.cpp render.h screenwriter.h
    g++ -c main.cpp render.h screenwriter.h -lSDL -lSDL_image

render.o : render.h render.cpp
    g++ -c render.h render.cpp -lSDL

screenwriter.o : screenwriter.h screenwriter.cpp
    g++ -c screenwriter.h screenwriter.cpp -lSDL -lSDL_image

clean:
    rm program main.o render.o screenwriter.o
```

the **nitty gritty**:

My goal with this is to have ScreenWriter implemented as a singleton to setup allegro and flag everything as needed through initialization. The second objective relies on render to just render by specifying x and y coordinates, along with a path to the file to render to load on the map. This is easy to do procedurally, but I'm ready to experiment with OO design on this.

So, any thoughts?

Comment: Wait, you're making SDL object oriented? [Hasn't someone already done that?](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)

Comment: That's fine if that's already been done. I've decided to do this the object oriented way so I can learn. Plus, SDL is a good graphics library.

Comment: yeah, I was merely pointing out that SDL was written with C in mind but SFML was written in C++. Plus many people say it's better-designed and faster than SDL.

Comment: If you really want to use an object oriented game library, I definitely second using SFML. It's much more straightforward and I feel is has a cleaner interface than SDL.

Comment: Really? Ok, I'll start using that then.

Comment: @Seth, SFML is not SDL -- it has waay to little supported platforms :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two syntax errors which are clear from your errors:

```
ScreenWriter * instance = ScreenWriter::get_instance();
```

should be

```
ScreenWriter & instance = ScreenWriter::get_instance();
```

because `get_instance` returns a reference, not a pointer, and

```
Render render = new Render("look.png", 0, 0, instance->get_screen());
```

should be

```
Render * render = new Render("look.png", 0, 0, instance->get_screen());
```

because `new` returns a pointer, not an object or reference.

Also,

```
delete instance();
```

should be

```
delete render;
```

because not only is the former completely wrong, but it's not being used on anything allocated by `new`. `render` is, however. So you have to `delete` it to avoid a memory leak.

I don't understand the "any thoughts" part of the question because it doesn't say about what. English isn't my first language though, so forgive me if I missed something.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the errors. But, could you tell me why my the object won't render and why SDL won't initialize? The program compiles and runs, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Holland you're not calling `Screenwriter::initialize` anywhere I see, so SDL isn't getting initalized. Also `delete instance();` should be `delete render;` (Corrected previous mistake)

Answer (score 0):

**Flip the screen after rendering the image**. When you blit something, it's blitted on a buffer. `SDL_Flip()` just swaps those buffers so that your o/p can be seen. So you should be replacing those two lines, I guess.

Comment: Uhm, you see the green check at the other answer? This means that the OP has accepted the answer, it helped him solve the problem. One year ago ;) Anyway, thanks for your effort.